# How to load more than one component using lazy loading in angular4?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

i have just started to learn angular4, and i am a little curious to learn the concept of lazy loading in angular4.
i have been going through [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html) article 
 and learned a little on lazy loading, but my question is in this article which i have mentioned above, there is only one component in the lazy module, what if i want more than one component in the lazy loading module, then how could i declare that in the route config of the lazy loading module. currently the route config for the lazy loading is

> const routes: Routes = [   { path: '', component: LazyComponent } ];

what if i want another component, then how would be my route config?

Comment: I do not believe you are currently lazy-loading with that configuration. Lazy loading according to the documentation https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-6-asynchronous-routing can be done with the loadChildren attribute.

Comment: plaese see my updated link

Comment: To answer your questions though, you wouldn't lazy load more than one component. Instead the lazy loaded component would have other components inside of it.

`<lazy-component>
    <nested-component></nested-component>
</lazy-component>`

Comment: @TommyMay cant there be anything like this in the lazy module route
const routes: Routes = [ 
{ path: '', component: LazyComponent } ,
{ path: '/anotherComponent', component: AnotherLazyComponent } 
];

Comment: @LijinJohn Yes, that approach would also work, and you would be injecting your components into the <router-outlet> used in app-root in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can define routes using `children` in your lazy modules' routes:

```
const gtPermitRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PermitComponent, children: [
        {path: '', component: PermitListComponent},
        {path: ':permitNumber', component: PermitDetailComponent},
     ]}
 ];
```

And any component you declare in your lazy module would be lazily loaded, including the components that don't appear in your routes, but used using selectors in your template:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        PermitComponent,
        PermitDetailComponent,
        AnotherComponent, // selector <app-another-component>
        PermitListComponent
    ],
    imports: [

    ]
})
export class PermitModule {}
```